# iPad (mobile Safari) select option font size inconsistency

Tags: css, ipad, webkit, mobile-safari, ios12

In my responsive web app, select option font size gets auto resized in iPad resulting each option text to have inconsistent font size. (screenshot from iOS12 iPad simulator)

[image]

I did research and tried everything that I came across:

- `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%` (to body)
- `-webkit-appearance: none` (to select)
- Wrap `<option>`s with `<optgroup>`
- set font-size of select to 16px in CSS

But none of them seemed to do anything.

```
<select>
  <option value="None"></option>
  <option value="1">Lorem ipsummmm sitamet consectetur</option>
  <option value="2">Adipisc elitsed eiusmod</option>
</select>
```

```
body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

select {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Here's [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqu5p96a/)

What I want to achieve is for the font size to be the same size regardless of option text length, if it's ever possible.

Comment: Facing same issue on iOS 13 as well. The font size for select dropdown text is inconsistent scross the rows.

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `font-size: 100%` to the body will fix this issue. This is caused because of the auto adjust in option values that are different due to length